# rhel + Metadata corruption detected at xfs

Tags: rhel, dmesg, xfs, corruption

due of linux electricity failure , our server crashed and reboot

now server is up

but  we see the following messages from dmesg

is it mean that OS damaged ?

```
[33505.670070] XFS (dm-2): Unmount and run xfs_repair
[33505.670071] XFS (dm-2): First 64 bytes of corrupted metadata buffer:
[33505.670072] ffff880223880000: 00 00 00 06 00 00 18 6b 00 00 00 16 00 00 4e f7  .......k......N.
[33505.670073] ffff880223880010: 00 00 00 40 00 00 f5 d8 00 00 00 74 00 01 90 d3  ...@.......t....
[33505.670074] ffff880223880020: 00 00 00 7e 00 01 b9 1b 00 00 00 9b 00 02 0f 53  ...~...........S
[33505.670075] ffff880223880030: 00 00 00 a0 00 02 24 f2 00 00 00 a3 00 02 3b 70  ......$.......;p
[33505.670097] XFS (dm-2): metadata I/O error: block 0x7f8af18 ("xfs_trans_read_buf_map") error 117 numblks 8
[33510.757046] XFS (dm-2): Metadata corruption detected at xfs_dir3_block_read_verify+0x5e/0x110 [xfs], block 0x7f8af18
[33510.757052] XFS (dm-2): Unmount and run xfs_repair
[33510.757053] XFS (dm-2): First 64 bytes of corrupted metadata buffer:
[33510.757055] ffff8803d4a48000: 00 00 00 06 00 00 18 6b 00 00 00 16 00 00 4e f7  .......k......N.
[33510.757080] ffff8803d4a48010: 00 00 00 40 00 00 f5 d8 00 00 00 74 00 01 90 d3  ...@.......t....
[33510.757081] ffff8803d4a48020: 00 00 00 7e 00 01 b9 1b 00 00 00 9b 00 02 0f 53  ...~...........S
[33510.757082] ffff8803d4a48030: 00 00 00 a0 00 02 24 f2 00 00 00 a3 00 02 3b 70  ......$.......;p
[33510.757096] XFS (dm-2): metadata I/O error: block 0x7f8af18 ("xfs_trans_read_buf_map") error 117 numblks 8
[33967.541321] XFS (dm-2): Metadata corruption detected at xfs_dir3_data_reada_verify+0x42/0x80 [xfs], block 0x7f8af18
[33967.541326] XFS (dm-2): Unmount and run xfs_repair
[33967.541327] XFS (dm-2): First 64 bytes of corrupted metadata buffer:
[33967.541330] ffff88027c7ef000: 00 00 00 06 00 00 18 6b 00 00 00 16 00 00 4e f7  .......k......N.
[33967.541331] ffff88027c7ef010: 00 00 00 40 00 00 f5 d8 00 00 00 74 00 01 90 d3  ...@.......t....
[33967.541332] ffff88027c7ef020: 00 00 00 7e 00 01 b9 1b 00 00 00 9b 00 02 0f 53  ...~...........S
[33967.541333] ffff88027c7ef030: 00 00 00 a0 00 02 24 f2 00 00 00 a3 00 02 3b 70  ......$.......;p
[33967.542417] XFS (dm-2): Metadata corruption detected at xfs_dir3_block_read_verify+0x5e/0x110 [xfs], block 0x7f8af18
[33967.542419] XFS (dm-2): Unmount and run xfs_repair
[33967.542419] XFS (dm-2): First 64 bytes of corrupted metadata buffer:
[33967.542421] ffff88027c7ef000: 00 00 00 06 00 00 18 6b 00 00 00 16 00 00 4e f7  .......k......N.
[33967.542422] ffff88027c7ef010: 00 00 00 40 00 00 f5 d8 00 00 00 74 00 01 90 d3  ...@.......t....
[33967.542423] ffff88027c7ef020: 00 00 00 7e 00 01 b9 1b 00 00 00 9b 00 02 0f 53  ...~...........S
[33967.542423] ffff88027c7ef030: 00 00 00 a0 00 02 24 f2 00 00 00 a3 00 02 3b 70  ......$.......;p
[33967.542461] XFS (dm-2): metadata I/O error: block 0x7f8af18 ("xfs_trans_read_buf_map") error 117 numblks 8
[33972.544095] XFS (dm-2): Metadata corruption detected at xfs_dir3_block_read_verify+0x5e/0x110 [xfs], block 0x7f8af18
[33972.544125] XFS (dm-2): Unmount and run xfs_repair
[33972.544127] XFS (dm-2): First 64 bytes of corrupted metadata buffer:
[33972.544130] ffff88065bcd0000: 00 00 00 06 00 00 18 6b 00 00 00 16 00 00 4e f7  .......k......N.
[33972.544132] ffff88065bcd0010: 00 00 00 40 00 00 f5 d8 00 00 00 74 00 01 90 d3  ...@.......t....
[33972.544133] ffff88065bcd0020: 00 00 00 7e 00 01 b9 1b 00 00 00 9b 00 02 0f 53  ...~...........S
[33972.544136] ffff88065bcd0030: 00 00 00 a0 00 02 24 f2 00 00 00 a3 00 02 3b 70  ......$.......;p
[33972.544157] XFS (dm-2): metadata I/O error: block 0x7f8af18 ("xfs_trans_read_buf_map") error 117 numblks 8
```

Comment: What type of drives ? Lying SSDs (they cheat on the write-ordering) ?  But take the machine up into single user and run xfs_repair on dm-2.

Comment: they are not SSH , this are vmdk disks

Comment: But that type is the hw disks ? Is it a esx host and the error is inside a virtual machine's disk ?